# ASP.NET MVC, CSS style only for Partial View like <style scoped>

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, css, asp.net-mvc-5

There is a new html attribute called [scoped](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_style_scoped.asp) but it is [now implemented only in firefox](http://caniuse.com/#feat=style-scoped). This attribute lets you to declare internal styles only for parent element.

I wonder if this is possible to emulate such behavior in ASP.NET MVC Partial View **without** creating some wrapper `<div class="wrapperOverPartial">`

Assume we have a view called `Infoes`

```cs
//some specific css here or css imported from file
<h2>Infoes</h2>

<address>  
    @Html.Partial("SomeSpecificInfo")
</address>
```

and partial view `SomeSpecificInfo`

```cs
<style>
       //some internal styles defined here
</style>
<h2>Some Specific Info</h2>
```

I want these style to be internal only for `SomeSpecificInfo` same way when using `scoped`, is this possible ?

Comment: ... use CSS classes? `<address class="specific-info">`

Comment: this is obvious one, but I mentioned in question that I want some attribute like `scoped` not a wrapper class

Comment: Or you could just add a CSS class to your `<address>` element and use that class as a prefix to define styles for your partial view in your main CSS.

Answer (score -2):

Define the css inline in the partial view. 
Inside `SomeSpecificInfo`

```
<style>
//Your custom class
</style>
 The rest of your partial view.
```

This will limit the scope of the classes only to `SomeSpecificInfo` page.

Comment: hmmm I have done this already and these inline styles impacts everything on the page.

Comment: You can try lex/ SASS if you want.

Comment: I am already using LESS but this is not a point of this question. I am only wondering if there is any directive, attribute or configuration in ASP.NET MVC which cuts the scope of inline css to the partial view it is declared in.